# how to find disabled-parent window from dialog

Tags: winapi, modal-dialog

I have a page (render in IE) that creates a model dialog with style: WS_POPUP - showModalDialog. I can find HWND of the dialog but how I can find the HWND of parent?
Because the model dialog and its parent run on different processes, API function getParent does not work. In addition! sometimes another window can stand between the dialog and parent page :(, This prevents me from using 'next window' :(.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) Short answer: *"It's one of those 'if you don't already know what the consequences are, then you are not smart enough to do it correctly' things."*

Answer (score 1):

There is no code, and *"API function getParent does not work"* isn't helpful. You should check with Spy++ parent value in `Properties`->`Windows`.

Please check also Remarks section in [GetParent documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633510(v=vs.85).aspx)

> To obtain a window's owner window, instead of using GetParent, use GetWindow with the GW_OWNER flag. To obtain the parent window and not the owner, instead of using GetParent, use GetAncestor with the GA_PARENT flag.

You have written:

> In addition! sometimes another window can stand between the dialog and parent page

This may suggest that you don't have true owner-owned relationship. Maybe it is only simulated by disabling your *owner* window and making your dialog *topmost*. You can verify this by using Spy++ looking for `WS_EX_TOPMOST` in `Properties`->`Styles`. With HideThatWindow application you can manipulate window styles on runtime and further confirm this.

For getting `HWND` I would post custom message from one window to other.

```
UINT MyWmMessage = RegisterWindowMessage( TEXT( "HereIsMyHWND.mydomainname.pl" ) );
...
PostMessage( DialogHWND, MyWmMessage, 0, (LPARAM) ParentHWND );
```

And in dialog window:

```
// If this is in another process, reregister custom message.
UINT MyWmMessage = RegisterWindowMessage( TEXT( "HereIsMyHWND.mydomainname.pl" ) );
...
LRESULT CALLBACK DialogWindowProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam )
{
    ...
    if ( msg == MyWmMessage )
    {
        WeGotParentHWND = (HWND) lparam;
    }
    ...
}
```